# Check in / Check out in subversion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

Hi I am using Ankh subversion in Visual Studio 2010. I would like get some silverlight project files from subversion and make some changes to the code, then commit my changes back to subversion

The subversion directory is as follows

Phase1\ViewerApp\trunk\Viewer

Phase1\ViewerApp\trunk\Viewer.Web

Phase1\ViewerApp\trunk\ViewerDeloyment

Can someone clarify the steps required to check in / check out to subversion.
When I tried to commit the files back to subversion, it came back with error 405 as the folder already exists

Comment: Not exactly sure what Ankh is, so I can't speak for absolute certainty, but did you do an `svn checkout` of the folders you listed above? You should be able to do `svn checkout URL/to/Phase1/ViewerApp/trunk` and it would checkout everything under that directory (unless there was a specific need to *only* checkout those directories).  

The error you're getting is usually due to you trying to do an `svn add` `svn commit` on directories that already exist in the repository. You should be **checking out**, **modifying** whatever files, _then_ **committing** (committing is the same as check in).

Comment: See this page if you receive the error `405 HTTP Method Not Allowed`: https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#four05 and https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.ankhsvn/wiki/AnkhFAQ#section-AnkhFAQ-IGetAnErrorSayingPROPFINDOf...405MethodNotAllowed

Answer (score 0):

If you use AnkhSVN in Visual Studio, read its [documentation](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html). You may also want to [try VisualSVN plug-in](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/) if there are issues with AnkhSVN

> Can someone clarify the steps required to check in / check out to
>   subversion.

With SVN you checkout *from repository*, make local changes, and commit them *to the repository* with `svn commit` command.